# Is there a way to check whether my device is currently using the 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz WiFi band?

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

If my Ubuntu device is connected to a dual-band WiFi SSID that uses both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz WiFi, then my understanding is that it will automatically switch between the two bands depending on which one has a stronger signal/better data rate. Is there any way to check which band my device is currently using?

Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hello. Check out this article and you will see that what you are saying is not correct. It does not jump bands.https://weakwifisolutions.com/does-a-dual-band-router-automatically-switch-to-the-fastest-band/

Comment: @David The link you give says: "A dual band router has two separate networks (2.4 GHz and 5 GHz), with separate Wi-Fi names and login credentials" None of the three wireless routers I have obtained in the last 24 months are configured this way by default.

Comment: Well mine is and so have everyone I have ever seen. Turn the router over what does it say on the bottom about names and passwords.

Comment: Keep in mind this may vary country by country.

Comment: Keep in mind that this may vary by manufacturer, as well. I would never, ever leave any router set to the default bottom passord and other details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your router is set, by default, to use the same network name (SSID) and login credentials and your wireless card is capable of both bands, then the router will, indeed, automatically switch as it deems necessary. Please check:

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

One of the listed networks will have an asterisk next to it * indicating it is in use. Here is an example from my machine:

```
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE   CHAN  RATE   SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
    xxxx  GBR1   Infra  11    540 Mbit/s  99      ▂▄▆█  WPA2 WPA>
```

- ```
    xxxx  GBR5   Infra  149   540 Mbit/s  92      ▂▄▆█  WPA2 WPA>
    xxxx  --     Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA2    >
    xxxx  DIRECT-Infra  149   130 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
  ```

I have redacted the BSSIDs (MAC addresses). As you see, I am connected to GBR5; its channel is 149, indicating it’s a 5 gHz channel.

You can also find out with:

```
iwconfig

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"GBR5"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: xxxx  
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm
```

As you see, the frequency is 5.745 gHz, obviously a 5 gHz frequency.

Because 5 gHz is always faster, I recommend that you rename the segments of your router; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

Comment: Nice answer. Good advice as well. I do not change mine the closest neighbor is 4 km away.